# Transformation of nested HTML span element

Tags: html, xslt-1.0

We are trying to transform an HTML template with placeholders into the final HTML using XSLT.

The (simplified) HTML template looks like:

```
<p>
  <span class="condition" id="v6">Some text here
    <span class="placeholder" id="v1" /> 
  </span>
</p>
```

The transformation should

- replace every `span` element with `placeholder` class;
- hide or show each `span` element that contains a `condition` class

The (simplified) XSLT we have is:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:local="urn:local"                   
                xmlns:s0="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

    <!-- Take the HTML template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Replace every placeholder in the HTML template with the value from the XML data-->
    <xsl:template match="span[@class='placeholder']">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="current()/@id"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'replaced'" />
    </xsl:template>


   <!-- Handle conditions based on custom logic -->
  <xsl:template match="span[@class='condition']">
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="current()/@id"/>
    <xsl:if test="$this = 'v6'">
      <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
    </xsl:if>   
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the placeholder span is not nested into the condition span, everything works fine. However, in the HTML example above, it doesn't work, the output is:

```
<p>Some text here</p>
```

We would like it to be:

```
<p>
  Some text here
    replaced       
</p>
```

It seems as if the condition is executed, but the placeholder is not executed or somehow overwritten; so basically, the placeholder span elements are not being replaced.

Does anyone has an explanation for this, and what we are doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile found a solution:

```
 <!-- Handle conditions based on custom logic -->
  <xsl:template match="span[@class='condition']">
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="current()/@id"/>
    <xsl:if test="$this = 'v6'">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>    <<<<----------------     
    </xsl:if>   
  </xsl:template>
```

Instead of taking the current text, I just re-apply the node.